# ¿Cómo puedo separar datos que están en una misma columna en Python?

Tags: python, jupyter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera obtener todos los datos relacionados con el mismo número de cuenta pero sin las palabras que están antes del =.
Es decir quisiera un data table de la siguiente manera

```
Cuenta      gestor  CELULAR   particular CELULAR  JERARQUIA  PARTICULAR 
9862640033  User    65555645  012235556  55477899 222333338  2566533566
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar a reemplazar los valores de la columna haciendo un split de la columna 'RefeTelefono'.

ejemplo:

```py
import pandas as pd
tabla = pd.DataFrame([[1,"asdf=123"],[2,"rqwg=5848"]], columns=['CUENTA','RefeTelefono'])
tabla['RefeTelefono'] = tabla['RefeTelefono'].str.split("=", n=1, expand=True)[1]
```

El valor de tabla después de la modificación es:

```
   CUENTA RefeTelefono
0       1          123
1       2         5848
```

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias